# How many days does the 30-month presence requirement for the US naturalization (N-400 form) represent?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I read on the U.S. [Naturalization Requirements Information](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/archive/g-1151_0.pdf?download=0) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200711041606/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/archive/g-1151_0.pdf?download=0)):

> An applicant for naturalization must [...] show that [they] have been physically present in the United States for 30 months.

How many days does the  30-month presence requirement for the US naturalization (N-400 form) represent? Is it `30*30` = 900 days or `365*5/2`=912.5 (~=912 or ~=913) days? Or some other amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [USCIS Policy Manual, Volume 12, Part D, Chapter 4](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-4), the physical presence requirement of at least 30 months means at least 913 days.